# Android Firebase Oauth Facebook not working in fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-authentication

Authenticating with Firebase Facebook is not working, here is my fragment code:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

private View mView;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    loginFacebook();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                //Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                //Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };

    return mView;
}


private void loginFacebook() {
    // Initialize Facebook Login button
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            // ...
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener((MainActivity)getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText((MainActivity)getActivity(), "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });
}
}
```

After the Facebook popup comes and I enter my username and password, nothing in the code is firing when in debug mode.

The Firebase user is always **null**. What am I doing wrong ?
After signing in it logs Log.d("LOGGER", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");

PS: The exact same code works when inserted in **MainActivity**

Comment: Is the onComplete listener ever triggered? Could you be a little more detailed in what you've tried and what the results were? It looks like you've commented out the relevant logs. How did you verify it's actually attempting to authenticate? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It goes in the AuthStateListener, and gives me Log.d("LOGGER", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");

Comment: Which it will do initially, until you actually log in. So again, how did you verify onComplete is ever called?

Answer (score 3):

You could try linking the fragment to the login button.

```
loginButton.setFragment(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I now know that I should use a Activity for login operation, and not a fragment.

However I had problem with getting the code to work in MainActivity, everything actually "worked". I got logged in, but my FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener did not return any user from firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().

So after some hours of testing I found out that enabling Email/Password in Sign-in method made it work. Weird...

At least I think this was the problem, however I did make a new Android project. And used: Tools -> firebase to generate a firebase project. But as I can recall this did not fix the problem, at least not immediately.

Or it may be because of the emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i just call the facebook default button from my custom button and left every single line of code as documented and bang it works sucessfully.

> 

```
public class SignInFragment extends Fragment implements
> FragmentChangeListener{
>     private Button facebook;
```

> ```
> private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
> private CallbackManager mCallBackManager;
> private LoginButton loginButton;
>
>
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>     // Inflate the layout for this fragment
>     View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in, container, false);
>
>     facebook = view.findViewById(R.id.facebookButton);
>     loginButton = view.findViewById(R.id.facebookBtn);
>
>     firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
>
>     facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             loginButton.callOnClick();
>         }
>     });
>
>     loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             mCallBackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
>             loginButton.setFragment(SignInFragment.this);
>             loginButton.setPermissions("email","public_profile");
>             loginButton.registerCallback(mCallBackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
>                     handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
>                 }
>
>                 @Override
>                 public void onCancel() {
>                     Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Is Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 }
>
>                 @Override
>                 public void onError(FacebookException error) {
>                     Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>     });
>
>     return view;
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>
>     mCallBackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>
> }
>
> private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
>     AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
>     firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
>             .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
>                     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>                         // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
>                         FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
>                         startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),MainActivity.class));
>                     } else {
>                         // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
>                         Toast.makeText(getContext(), task.getException().getMessage(),
>                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                     }
>
>                 }
>             });
> }
> ```
>
> }